# Exhaling While Using an Angel's Name

Tags: malach-angel, havdalah

[This](https://ohr.edu/ask/ask106.htm) article quotes Rav Yaakov Yisrael Kanievsky as saying

> There's an angel whose name is the same as the sound produced when you
> blow out with force. According to Kabbalistic tradition, it's improper
> to make use of the names of holy angels. Many people, therefore,
> extinguish candles by hand in order not to pronounce the name of this
> angel.

Although they quote a few sources, I didn't see anyone mention the Steipler saying this - what is the source for this? (If the Steipler *did* say this, would it then also be a problem to breathe out for stress relief since you're "using" the name of this angel too?

Comment: It's mentioned in the Kol Bo,Eliya Rabbah ,Ben Ish Chai...see Shmerias Haguf Vhanefesh 267:8,I don't recall the Angel name thing though